# Serializing to memory and then encrypting

Tags: c#, serialization, encryption

```
Object p=new Object();
//stream-this is the stream to the file.

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     BinaryFormatter msSeri = new BinaryFormatter();
     msSeri.Serialize(ms, p);

     DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
     cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
     cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");       
     CryptoStream crStream = new                        
     CryptoStream(ms,cryptic.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);
     byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ms.ToString());
     crStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
     crStream.Close();
     BinaryFormatter seri = new BinaryFormatter();
     if (stream != null)
         seri.Serialize(stream, seri.Deserialize(crStream));
}
```

I need to serialize to file only the encrypted data,so i've tried to serialize to memory first,then encrypt,then serialize to file.
i got Argument exception in this line-

```
seri.Serialize(stream, seri.Deserialize(crStream));
```

i'm new at this,any help will be welcomed.
i dont know if how i did it is even correct,i used examples i found all over the web.

Comment: If you want to write the encrypted data to a file use a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream.

Comment: I see you close stream with crStream.Close(); then you use it in deserialization, it may cause the problem.

Comment: i tried moving it to the end of the code and still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string path = "D:\\changeit.txt";
        Object p = new Object();

        using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
        {           
            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            using (CryptoStream crStream = new
                  CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stream.ToString());
                crStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                BinaryFormatter seri = new BinaryFormatter();
                seri.Serialize(crStream, p);
            }
        }
```

Basically you need one FileStream and one CryptoStream. And use using(), no close().

Example for deserializing:

```
        using (Stream readStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            using (CryptoStream crStream = 
                new CryptoStream(readStream, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(readStream.ToString());
                crStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                object obj = formatter.Deserialize(crStream);                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: you're the best :)) it's working. how can i know if it is really going through the encryption stages?                                                                                              in this code-i only serialize to file the encrypted data,right?no unencrypted data is serialized

Comment: We are writing data from CryptoStream, they should be encrypted. You can do some experiments with reasonable data and then check data is encrypted.

Comment: there's the closing bracket of the second "using".                                                  i started my program added things,closed it and when i reopened it says on that bracket-bad data..

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, using need two brackets. What do you mean by reopening?

Comment: using (CryptoStream crStream = 
                new CryptoStream(readStream, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(readStream.ToString());
                crStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                object obj = formatter.Deserialize(crStream);                    
            }                                                                                                           in this last bracket is says-Bad Data.

Comment: Is it runtime error? Any details where this bad data is? Are you using obj further?

Comment: yes runtime error.when i'm using debugging it marks the last bracket and says "Bad data.". i'm using obj only in one line after,i add him to a list.

Comment: when i add objects during the running of the program,they are serialized to file after the encryption.                                                                                    upon starting the program again,it should decrypt and deserialize these objects-but it only gives me the last object entered..                                       any suggestions on what to change in the code you gave?

Comment: It is difficult to see what is wrong without seeing the code. BinaryFormatter can work with any number of objects if you are serializing them one by one and then deserializing them.

Comment: stream = File.OpenWrite("f15.bin");
            using (stream)
            {
                DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stream.ToString());
                    crStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Comment: BinaryFormatter seri = new BinaryFormatter();
                    seri.Serialize(crStream, p);
                }
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                 this is how i serialize. is there a possibility that everytime i do this,the file is been overwritten and that's why only 1 object appears?

Comment: Yes, if you are calling this several times each time you are overwriting everything when you do File.OpenWrite  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You need to call this only once and call seri.Serialize(crStream, p); inside of it several times - for each object you need to serialize. The same for deserialization. Hope this helps.

Comment: i need your help,i'm initializing the stream this way:stream=File.OpenWrite(path)- i dont immediately serialize items.              in the proccess of the program,when the user chooses to add something like a product,he fills the neccessary information and then a function called AddProduct,adds the product to the database and there it serializes to file. is there anything different i need to do,when i'm there?

Comment: Logically you need a function which will do serialization, it will include File.OpenWrite, encryption and serialization itself. Do all the preparation before and call this serialization function when it is necessary. Decompose your program to classes/functions.

Comment: if i call this function each time i have an object to serialize,it will still overwrite the data in the file the next time i'll call this function,won't it?

Comment: File.OpenWrite overwrites file. If you call it again, your data will be overwritten. It is better to prepare data beforehand and call serialization.